# How to stop a process programmatically

Tags: c++, process, system

I would like to ask how can I stop a process programmatically using C++?

Thanks.

Comment: You could build a robot that unplugs power cables; that would be relatively platform independent.

Comment: @Pavel: It depends on how you write the requirements. :-)

Comment: @James McNellis: tell the OP how to build the robot in C++.

Comment: Depends what you mean by stop. Do you mean STOP or HALT these seem like law enforcement activities so @James robot should suffice, while if you mean KILL this is more militaristic and thus @pavel rocket launcher would do the trick.

Comment: @Pavel even this is not enough. Haven't you see Terminator?

Answer (score 4):

This is a platform dependent question.  Could you specify the platform you're worknig on?

For Windows you can use `TerminateProcess`

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It's platform-dependent. On Unix you'd send the process a signal with the [`kill(2)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/kill/).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`exit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/exit/) function to terminate the calling process. If you want to terminate the process without executing destructors for objects of automatic or static storage duration you could use [`abort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abort/) function.

Comment: @Kyrill - I sure hope OP means a _different_ process, otherwise this must be a dup

Comment: @Steve, I'll delete my answer when OP will reveal this possible misunderstanding. It is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
 system("taskkill /f /im process.exe"); 
// replace process.exe with the name of process you want to stop/kill
// /f is used to forcefully terminate the process
// /im is used for imagename or in simple word it's like wildcard
 return 0;
}
```

Or you can go to [How to kill processes by name? (Win32 API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956519/how-to-kill-processes-by-name-win32-api)