# Need help forcefully terminating a process in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

From vb.net, I need to terminate a process that often hangs. I normally use process.kill, which works on most processes, but not on a hung process. If I use taskkill /im process.exe it does not terminate either. But if I use taskkill /im process.exe /f, it terminates fine. So the questions is, what is the vb.net equivalent for taskkill /f?

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I kill a process using Vb.NET or C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a ProcessStartInfo with your arguments and the file name, in this case "taskkill" then you can start the process and it will run the taskkill command. This is a Subroutine that you can call that will do it. you will need to put `Imports System.Diagnostics` at the top of your Class file.

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        KillHungProcess("Notepad.exe") 'Put your process name here
    End Sub
    Public Sub KillHungProcess(processName As String)
        Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo
        psi.Arguments = "/im " & processName & " /f"
        psi.FileName = "taskkill"
        Dim p As Process = New Process()
        p.StartInfo = psi
        p.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I thought of that, but since XP Home does not have taskkill, I would rather use .net or API to get it done. We still have a lot of clients using XP, so would like to use taskkill as a last resort. Any idea how to accomplish this using API or .net?

Comment: See if this SO questions accepted answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/7956651/479512

Comment: I was figuring there would be an easy way using vb.net, but since there is not I will just use taskkill via process.start and not worry about XP Home.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Shell("taskkill /F /IM process-name-here.exe /T", 0)

End Sub
```